# Increasing `paddingbottom` decreases button's height, but doesn't change padding

Tags: android, layout, padding

When I increase `paddingbottom` in my Android layout, the button's text padding is not changed, but its height is decreased.

The code is as below. When I add the code `android: paddingBottom="10dp"` to the first button. The button's height shrunk. It changed as below. Could someone give me some suggestions?

[image]
[image]

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"

            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="C"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn_clear"
            android:gravity="right|bottom"
            android:background="@drawable/white_selector"

            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="DEL"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn_del"
            android:gravity="right|bottom"
            android:background="@drawable/white_selector"


            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="/"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn_devide"
            android:gravity="right|bottom"
            android:background="@drawable/white_selector"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="*"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn_mulitply"
            android:gravity="right|bottom"
            android:background="@drawable/white_selector"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should change LinearLayout **center_horizontal** to **center**.

when LinearLayout gravity=center_horizontal.

The sub view clear button from LinearLayout will center_vertical.

Comment: Is the  LinearLayout gravity=center_horizontal working on the button or the text on the button?

Answer (score 0):

The problem occur because you set **android:orientation="horizontal"** for LinearLayout. All button are same **height** , so if u just set **padding** for only **Clear** button, this button will move down.
I suggues you add **android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"** to **Clear** button ,and **android:layout_marginTop="10dp"** for another button like this :

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="C"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn_clear"
            android:gravity="right|bottom"
            android:background="@drawable/white_selector" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="DEL"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn_del"
            android:gravity="right|bottom"
            android:background="@drawable/white_selector"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="/"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn_devide"
            android:gravity="right|bottom"
            android:background="@drawable/white_selector"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="*"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn_mulitply"
            android:gravity="right|bottom"
            android:background="@drawable/white_selector" />
    </LinearLayout>
```